# How many times is the resize() method called?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Could you please explain why the right answer is logarithmic? I did not get it.

Suppose that, starting from an empty data structure, we perform `n` push operations in our resizing-array implementation of a stack. How many times is the `resize()` method called?

a) constant

b) logarithmic (Correct. The `resize()` method is called only when the size of the stack is a power of 2. There are ~log2n powers of 2 between 1 and `n`.)

c) linear

d) quadratic

Comment: "in our resizing-array" how we are supposed to know how resize is implemented and called in that implementation if you didn't provide any code? Please add code of that structure, or specify if this question is about one of existing implementations like `java.lang.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Does `resize()` double the capacity on each call?

Comment: Only by looking at the code can one determine the growth policy of any collection implementation.  If you're  talking about the JDK, it is implementation dependent and not really necessary to use the class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accommodate a new element, a completely filled dynamic array (or resizing-array as you call it) doubles its capacity when pushing the new element. This is true for most common implementations of dynamic array.

Initially, your stack (implemented through a dynamic array) is empty. When you push the first element, it resizes to a capacity of 1 element. When you push second, it resizes to a capacity of 2 elements. When you push third, it resizes to a capacity of 4 elements. So, there is no resizing for 4th element. But when you push 5th, it now resizes to a capacity of 8. And it goes so on.

So if you are pushing `n` elements, `resize()` will be called when pushing 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 9th, 17th, ..., elements.

So how many times is `resize()` being called? If you ignore the 1st element, `resize()` is being is called when pushing `(2^k + 1)th` elements, where `k = 0,1,2,3,4,5...`. Since there are nearly `log2(n)` such numbers in range `[1,n]`, that's the number of times `resize()` will be called. Hence, logarithmic is the correct answer.